# send byte array from unity to javasript

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

This is my byte array on Unity side.

```
byte[] array1 = new byte[(int)size1];
```

and I want to send it to .jslib like this

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void LoadJavaScriptFile(byte[] array,int size);
```

but I don't know how to handle this byte array on JS side.

```
const buffer =new ArrayBuffer(arraySize);
const newByteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```

And then what should I do?

Comment: There is a similar question asked on Unity forums:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/send-byte-array-to-js.408091/

Comment: I've already checked it. but I don't want iterate something. I just need the pure byte array. can I can copy unity array to js array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lexion said, the unity documentary was self-explanatory.
I just recreated the array.

```
      const newArray =new ArrayBuffer(arraySize);
      const newByteArray = new Uint8Array(newArray);
      console.log(newByteArray.length);
      for(var i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
      newByteArray[i]=HEAPU8[array1 + i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line

```
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(HEAPU8.buffer, array, size);
```